# Is llvm-clang compiler localized?

Tags: clang

I am looking for some insignts, is Clang localized? I mean error messages, hints, warnings, some other output, can they be displayed in the language other than english? If yes, how to achieve that? Changing system locale or parameter switch or download localized copy?

In particular I am looking for Russian and Chinese languages,

Answer (score 0):

Short asnwer: [Not yet](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#internals-diag-translation). But maybe later.